# Why BULK INSERT insert data in random order?

Tags: sql-server, csv, bulk-insert

I have a `csv` file with 350,000 rows. Would like to insert data to temporary table in same order as is in `csv` file. I am trying to `BULK INSERT` using:

```
BULK INSERT ##AllRows
    FROM @FilePath
    WITH
    (
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '\n'
    )
```

Unfortunately `BULK INSERT` inserts data in random order. My header in every execution is in different row. I ran it on SQL Server 2016. Is there a possibility that in older versions of SQL Server order manner was different?

Using the `FIRSTROW` option does not recognize header as first row of file. File does not have any column for which we can order. In file always header is in first row.

It could be a coincidence but even with `FIRSTROW=2` it is possibility that my header will be in table. I checked it. It looks like the more rows `csv` file contains the more chance that insert to table will be with random order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rows from the file *are* read in order, and added to the table in the same order.

The issue occurs when you *read* rows from the table. Without an `ORDER BY` clause on your `SELECT`, SQL Server is free to return rows from the table in whatever order is convenient.

#### Details

The question doesn't provide a definition for the table `##AllRows`, but it seems certain the table is a heap (a table without a clustered index). SQL Server reads pages from a heap using Index Allocation Map (IAM) structures. This means data tends to be returned in file and page id order within each IAM chain, which will generally not reflect the order in which data was inserted. This is the underlying cause of the behaviour you are seeing.

#### Solutions

You need a column to indicate the order of rows in the file, then order by that column when you write your query. Unfortunately, SQL Server does not provide a built-in way to add this 'sequence' column during import.

There are a couple of common workarounds:

1. Pre-process the source file outside SQL Server to add a sequence number to each row. This is the most reliable method.
2. Assign a sequence number during the import.

The second method carries some risk because there is no documented guarantee that this will work reliably in all circumstances. Nevertheless, people have been using this idea successfully for a long time. The general idea is:

- Add an `IDENTITY` column to the import table.
- Create a view over the import table, omitting the `IDENTITY` column.
- `BULK INSERT` into the view.

This will not work with a global temporary table, because a view cannot reference that type of table. You would need to use a regular table (perhaps in *tempdb*) instead.

#### Example 1

I used the following script to successfully import [a csv file](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/100) containing the Complete Works of Shakespeare:

The first step is to create a table in *tempdb* with an extra `IDENTITY` column:

```
USE tempdb;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test
(
    id integer IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    line nvarchar(4000) NOT NULL
);
```

Now we create a view over that table, omitting the `IDENTITY` column:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.ImportTest
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT
    T.line
FROM dbo.Test AS T;
```

Finally, we bulk insert into the view:

```
BULK INSERT dbo.ImportTest
FROM 'C:\Temp\shakespeare.txt'
WITH 
(
    CODEPAGE = '65001',
    DATAFILETYPE = 'char',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
);
```

We can now see the first few lines in file order using a `SELECT` with `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT TOP (20)
    T.id,
    T.line
FROM dbo.Test AS T 
ORDER BY
    T.id ASC;
```

The result shows the text in the right order:

[image: Query result]

#### Example 2

It is also possible to use `OPENROWSET` with a format file. Using the same example csv file, I was able to import the data using the following format file (saved as `shakespeare.xml`):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="line" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR" NULLABLE="NO"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

and:

```
INSERT dbo.Test
    WITH (TABLOCK)
    (
        line
    )
SELECT
    ORO.line
FROM OPENROWSET
(
    BULK 'C:\Temp\shakespeare.txt',
    FORMATFILE = 'C:\Temp\shakespeare.xml',
    CODEPAGE = '65001'
) AS ORO;
```

Notice that this method does not require a view, so you could target a global temporary table. The target table still needs the extra `IDENTITY` column.

Answer (score 0):

Guide Bulk Insert along your csv by use of parameters ...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

specifically :

FIRSTROW = first_row -> first line to import from file (starts counting from 1)

KEEPIDENTITY -> Specifies that identity value or values in the imported data file are to be used for the identity column. If KEEPIDENTITY is not specified, the identity values for this column are verified but not imported and SQL Server automatically assigns unique values based on the seed and increment values specified during table creation. If the data file does not contain values for the identity column in the table or view, use a format file to specify that the identity column in the table or view is to be skipped when importing data; SQL Server automatically assigns unique values for the column. For more information, see DBCC CHECKIDENT (Transact-SQL).

ORDER ( { column [ ASC | DESC ] } [ ,... n ] ) -> Specifies how the data in the data file is sorted. Bulk import performance is improved if the data being imported is sorted according to the clustered index on the table, if any. If the data file is sorted in a different order, that is other than the order of a clustered index key or if there is no clustered index on the table, the ORDER clause is ignored. The column names supplied must be valid column names in the destination table. By default, the bulk insert operation assumes the data file is unordered. For optimized bulk import, SQL Server also validates that the imported data is sorted.

n Is a placeholder that indicates that multiple columns can be specified.

Edit: Sorry to read that it didn't outright help you - but I found this near the end of said page:

Importing Data from a CSV file
Beginning with SQL Server 2017 (14.x) CTP 1.1, BULK INSERT supports the CSV format, as does Azure SQL Database. Before SQL Server 2017 (14.x) CTP 1.1, comma-separated value (CSV) files are not supported by SQL Server bulk-import operations. However, in some cases, a CSV file can be used as the data file for a bulk import of data into SQL Server. For information about the requirements for importing data from a CSV data file, see [Prepare Data for Bulk Export or Import (SQL Server).](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/prepare-data-for-bulk-export-or-import-sql-server?view=sql-server-2016)

Comment: Thank you for advice but these parameters did not help with this problem. FIRSTROW does not recognize header as first row of file. File does not have any column for which we can order. In file always header is in first row.

Comment: @axdna "does not recognize header" can you please elaborate? Are you saying that when you used `FIRSTROW = 2` the header row was still imported? Are you sure the header row only exists in the file once? Are you sure it has the same rowterminator? Can you supply a sample of this file somewhere, the definition of the table, and the exact command you say doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: It is very strange to be honest... I created new csv file from file with 350 000 rows wih top 10 rows and now this new file (with 10 rows) is inserting in order from file (so header is first)...

Comment: "Inserting in order" is a happy coincidence and can't be relied on. `FIRSTROW=2` will eliminate the first row in the file, regardless of what order the data ends up in the table, which could be a completely different order. A table is not a file.

Comment: Yes it could be coincidence but even with ```FIRSTROW=2``` it is possibility that my header will be in table. I checked it. It looks like the more rows ```csv``` file contains the more chance that insert to table will be with random order.

Comment: @axdna Not how it works (unless you are inserting over and over again into the same `##AllRows` table that already has header rows in there) so, please, post a full repro somewhere.